# Задача на нахождение числа, произведение цифр которого, равно другому числу C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=669):

> Найти наименьшее и наибольшее натуральные числа, произведение цифр в
> которых равно заданному натуральному числу M или сообщить, что таких
> чисел не существует. Для записи искомых чисел нельзя использовать
> цифры 0 и 1.
>
> **Входные данные** В единственной строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано
> натуральное число M (2 ≤ M ≤ 1000).
>
> **Выходные данные** В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно
> вывести два натуральных числа в неубывающем порядке. Если таких чисел
> не существует, то вывести -1 -1.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool check_prime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (size_t i = 11; i * i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        if (check_prime(i) && n % i == 0) //если существует простой делитель больше 9, то число непредставимо
        {
            cout << -1 << " " << -1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    vector<int> a,b; //a - максимальное, b - минимальное 
    int m = n;
    for (size_t i = 2; i < 10 && n != 1; i++)
    {
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            a.push_back(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 9; i > 1 && m != 1; i--)
    {
        while (m % i == 0)
        {
            b.push_back(i);
            m /= i;
        }
    }
    for (auto i = b.rbegin(); i != b.rend(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i;
    }
    cout << " ";
    for (auto i = a.rbegin(); i != a.rend(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i;
    }
}
```

На одном из тестов неверный ответ. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте возьмем число... ну... 57 = 3*19, вот.

Пошла ваша проверка...

```
for (size_t i = 11; i * i <= n; i += 2)
```

Стоп-стоп! 11*11==121, явно больше 57 - значит, мы проскакиваем эту проверку вообще!

Досадно, но идем дальше, потому что еще не все потеряно...

```
for (size_t i = 2; i < 10 && n != 1; i++)
{
    while (n % i == 0)
    {
        a.push_back(i);
        n /= i;
    }
}
```

Вот здесь бы проверить, а не осталось ли `n` большим 1 (реально - большим 10), но раз мы этого не делаем - вот теперь уже да, таки все потеряно. Программа выведет `3 3`, что, как вы понимаете, как ни множь - никак не даст 57...

Я бы вашу проверку с 11 (понимаете, в чем ее ошибка?...) убрал вообще и проверял бы число уже после разложения на простые однозначные.